# Wildcard certificate key value mismatch on single server

Tags: ssl, certificate, nginx

We're updating the wild card cert in all our servers this month, including three nginx proxy servers. Two of those worked right away, the third gets this error:

nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/etc/pki/tls/private/domain.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)

The same cert works for the web interface and webmin. Tried creating a self-signed cert to test and got the same error. All three servers are on Centos 7 and nginx 1.16.1.

We're using the PEM file with the cert and intermediate cert, but also tried with just the cert. Other suggestions?

Comment: You have a mismatch between your key and certificate, so I wonder how it worked on two computers. This error usually means that the certificates are concatenated wrongly. You should concatenate certificate and bundle as `cat certificate.crt ca_bundle.crt > bundle_chained.crt` and then in the config use "ssl_certificate     bundle_chained.crt;". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52261299/165358) for example.

Comment: Agreed, and that is how the files are built on all 3 servers

Comment: Some cleaning of the already installed certificates might be needed.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Found the problem.  To simplify the annual certificate updates, all references to the certificate and key use a generic filename instead of one that included the year of the cert.  Out of the 178 ports listed in the reverse proxy config, 1 was pointing to the original certificate file name instead of the generic one.

Comment: So you did some cleaning and found the problem. Good.